# Pressing the powerbutton does not do anything in Ubuntu (no menu)

Tags: unity, 14.04, shutdown, menu, x230

When pressing the powerbutton in Xubuntu 14.04 a menu prompt would show and allow me to logout/shutdown/... etc.

Now that I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 this is not the case anymore.

How can I activate this menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Command-line method:**

Open a terminal by first pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and the typing "terminal") and type the following:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power "interactive"
```

**Graphical method:**

For a graphical way to get the menu, you need to install `dconf-editor`; install it from the software center by typing the name of the application or from a terminal using `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor` and then open the application by first pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then typing `dconf-editor`.

On opening the application, from the left side menu go to **org -> gnome -> settings-daemon -> plugins -> power** and then in "button-power" choose "interactive".

Comment: Both options don't work. :( The CLI method does not have an effect. The second method does not work because there is no section for `org`. Here's a screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yqpw3w8nxd9z2s0/powerbutton.png

Comment: @king_julien: Are you able to auto-complete when you start typing `gsettings set org.gnome.settin` using the tab key?

Comment: Yes, up until `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power`.

Comment: Aha! I finally figured out what's going on. 2 things: 1) I mistakenly used the `gconf-editor` instead of the `dconf-editor` 2) The power-button press works. But I have to **press is it for about a second at least** in order for the menu to reveal itself.

Comment: in my case, the key was `power-button-action`